# How to increment through sprite locations in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, html5-canvas, sprite

So I have a string array with the sprites I want to display:

```
var lts = [
    "letterA",
    "letterB",
    "letterC",
    "letterD",
    "letterE",
    "letterF"
];
```

in my `assets.js` I load them:

```
function loadAssets(callback){

    function loadSprite(fileName){
        assetsStillLoading++;

        let spriteImage = new Image();
        spriteImage.src = "assets/sprites/" + fileName;

        spriteImage.onload = function()
        {
            assetsStillLoading--;
        }

        return spriteImage;
    }
    sprites.background = loadSprite('spr_background_pink.png');

    sprites.letterA = loadSprite('/Letters/letter_A.png');
    sprites.letterB = loadSprite('/Letters/letter_B.png');
    sprites.letterC = loadSprite('/Letters/letter_C.png');
    sprites.letterD = loadSprite('/Letters/letter_D.png');
    sprites.letterE = loadSprite('/Letters/letter_E.png');
    sprites.letterF = loadSprite('/Letters/letter_F.png');
}
```

Now I want to be able to cycle through this letter options to select the correct one, like so:

```
letterNo = letterNo + 1;

var string = "sprites." + lts[letterNo];
console.log("sprite loading:" + string);
this.sprite = string;
```

But when I try I get:

`sprites.letterB` in the debugger which is the sprite I want to load, but it doesn't like it:

> TypeError: Argument 1 of CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage could not be converted to any of:        HTMLImageElement, SVGImageElement, HTMLCanvasElement, HTMLVideoElement, ImageBitmap.

How can I get this to work please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"sprites.letterB"` is just a string that has no relation to the sprites object. If you want to access a key in the sprites object, use the bracket notation: `sprites[lts[letterNo]]`.

Comment: Oh my! Thanks a lot, new to js, was close, but couldn't see the wood for the trees!

Comment: so is this like casting the string to be type "sprites"?

Comment: No, sprites is not a type, it is a variable that holds an object which basically works like an associative array. It has string keys that point to values, and you fetch the key by providing it inside the square brackets, much like when you use numerical indices in a normal array.